# What is the difference between has_one and embeds_one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I noticed that in the [Mongoid relations documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html) that they refer to both has_one and embeds_one. What is the difference between these two things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documents are on differents collections, with the relation `has_one`.

Otherwise, a parent document has `embeds_one` child document on his same collection.

You can take a look to http://www.slideshare.net/mdirolf/mongodb-how-it-works

I wait help you!

Regards!